# Add an onTouch event for Action_Down and _up to a button during runtime to play a sound while button is pressed

Tags: android, button, media-player, ontouchlistener

I want to create a button during run time. The button should start playing a sound when it is pressed and stop playing when the the user stops pressing the button.

Browsing the web and Stack Overflow I come up with this code:

```
    // Create a new button and place it into a table row
    LinearLayout lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
    Button b1 = new Button(this);
    lnr.addView(b1);

    // Associate the event
    b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Finger started pressing --> play sound in loop mode
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( PATH );
                    mp.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Finger released --> stop playback
                try {
                    mp.stop();
                } catch (Exception e) {} 
          }
          return true;
        }
      });
```

The problem is that I do not hear a sound at all. It seems to me that the `case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:` is directly triggered. Therefore, the playback is directly stopped.

To test this hypothesis, I removed `mp.stop();` and heard an infinite loop of the sound. It is quite clear though that it must be the ACTION_UP event that screwed everything up. But how can the ACTION_UP event be triggered if I don't release the finger/mouse?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You should insert '**break**' at the bottom of 'case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN'.

Comment: Of course ... I was so concerned with finding a problem with the MediaPlayer object or the MotionEvent that I missed the obvious.

Thank you! 

I have corrected the code and attached it below.

Comment: I just realized that this works only once. I click the button and hear the sound loop. I release the button and the playback stops immediately. One also has to add mp.reset(); after mp.stop();

Answer (score 1):

The correct code is:

```
    // Create a new button and place it into a table row
    LinearLayout lnr = (LinearLayout) findViewById(R.id.tableRow3);
    Button b1 = new Button(this);
    lnr.addView(b1);

    // Associate the event
    b1.setOnTouchListener(new OnTouchListener() {
        MediaPlayer mp = new MediaPlayer();
        @Override
        public boolean onTouch(View v, MotionEvent event) {
            switch(event.getAction() & MotionEvent.ACTION_MASK) {
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_DOWN:
                // Finger started pressing --> play sound in loop mode
                try {
                    FileInputStream fileInputStream = new FileInputStream( PATH );
                    mp.setDataSource(fileInputStream.getFD());
                    mp.prepare();
                    mp.setLooping(true);
                    mp.start();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            break;
            case MotionEvent.ACTION_UP:
                // Finger released --> stop playback
                try {
                    mp.stop();
                    mp.reset();
                } catch (Exception e) {}
            break;
          }
          return true;
        }
      });
```